# Dell PowerEdge c6145 Node Server no vga display, boot or bios... Any ideas?

Tags: dell-poweredge

I have a dell PowerEdge c6145 server. node #1 works fine in both of the slots. i can boot and get display, bios, os, etc.

i just got a second node #2 brand new. it wont boot, no VGA, no post, etc... both should be identical ram and CPU's. there are 2 redundant 1100 watt PSU's. i highly doubt its the motherboard.. each node has four socket G-34 AMD 6276 CPU's

tried swapping power supplies. even re-seating chips and ram with no success.

any ideas? is there a jumper on the motherboard i'm missing? thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it turn on at all, fans spin?

Comment: This sounds like a whole lot of effort to put into a system that should be under warranty since it's brand new.  Call support.

Comment: I came into a second hand machine... it gets power to the board, as i see some leds lighting up. the network port lights up.  and the initial power cycle the fans spin really loud then tone down a bit but still no vga out... also no devices are present in the pci slots. The mavhine isnt under warranty as far as i know? or is there some type of support i can still get from dell?

Comment: could the mpt2 lsi sas controller affect the node from booting? lack of drivers or something?

Answer (score 0):

Apply BIOS reset. It should be jumper on the board for that, check the technical manual.

If also after that you do not even get VGA output anyway, I think, that's the end. It may not boot for a number of reasons but BIOS setup screen normally comes up.